# UIButtons unresponsive when put along with EAGLView

Tags: iphone, uikit, opengl-es

In my iPhone game, I have an EAGLView where OpenGL rendering happens. Above it I have 2 UIButtons placed in the XIB. Once the EAGLView Viewcontroller is pushed, for the first few seconds, the UIButtons are unresponsive.

But the OpenGL rendering happens seamlessly. Has anyone suffered from a similar problem ? Any pointers on what could be wrong ?

I brought the render time interval from 1.0f/60.0f to 1.0f/30.f, still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read somewhere that ui elements above the opengl layer don't really work correctly unless you pause the opengl layer

Comment: thank you very much.. your hint helped me solve the issue.. I added this line in the viewDidLoad


 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(startOpengl) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];